# netflix wont go full screen when using other programs

Tags: 13.10, netflix

I'm using 2 monitors and I like to surf Reddit while watching netflix and when I click on another window it stops going full screen is there anyway lock it on fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Right click it and check "Stay in fullscreen"